# boost program options choices

Tags: c++, boost-program-options, command-line-arguments

Is there a simple way to check if the argument of an option is inside a set of predefined choices? "Simple" here means without defining an ad-hoc class.

Suppose I have the option `--myoption` which must have value `"myvalue1"` or `"myvalue2"`

For example in python is really easy with [choices option in optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.choices)

Comment: Wouldn't this just be comparing strings? Assuming they are both `std::string`, you could do `if ((arg == myvalue1) || (arg == myvalue2))`.

Comment: sure, it works, but I need something more integrated in `program-options` (for example it can change the help message), for example working with non-string

Comment: You might want to explain more about what you want to do, it is unclear.

Comment: @JesseGood: very simple, I want if user types `--myoption myvalue3` the program should raise an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost program options allowed set of input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820109/boost-program-options-allowed-set-of-input-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sets of mutually exclusive options in boost program options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577107/sets-of-mutually-exclusive-options-in-boost-program-options)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15577107/2597135

Answer (score 0):

As I've just realized, you can define two mutually exclusive options simply defining a small function as explained in [real.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/program_options/example/real.cpp). For example, you can specify two conflicting options defining a `conflicting_options()` function:

```
void conflicting_options(const boost::program_options::variables_map & vm,
                         const std::string & opt1, const std::string & opt2)
{
    if (vm.count(opt1) && !vm[opt1].defaulted() &&
        vm.count(opt2) && !vm[opt2].defaulted())
    {
        throw std::logic_error(std::string("Conflicting options '") +
                               opt1 + "' and '" + opt2 + "'.");
    }
}
```

and then calling

```
conflicting_options (vm, "quiet", "verbose");
```

right after `boost::program_options::store()`

Checking that `--myoption` is equal to `myvalue1` or `myvalue2` then becomes just a matter of a function call.

I still don't understand if it's possible to define two mutually exclusive positional options, but that should be another question.