# Sets of mutually exclusive options in boost program options

Tags: c++, boost-program-options, command-line-arguments

My program (`prog.exe`) supports the following four flags: `-P`, `-p` , `-b` and `-s`. However:

- `-b` and `-p` must be specified together, constitute a set, and have numeric values e.g. `-b 42`
- `-s` cannot be specified with the above set, and vice versa
- `-P` is mandatory in both cases

As such `prog.exe` can only be run as either

```
prog.exe -P -s
```

or

```
prog.exe -P -b -42 -p 8
```

Is there a way to specify the above sets of mutually exclusive command line options in boost program options?

Comment: That's part of logic to implement in the (obligate) `parseOptions()` method of a `boost::program_options` client application IMHO.

Comment: I've come along such situations, and usually map them to some 'program execution mode' enum options. I first lookup option settings for this and after determining it, proceed with the specific options ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should start with a few tutorials [[1]](http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-program_options)[[2]](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/07/manage-command-line-boost-program-options/) to understand how `boost::program_options` works.

Then, you can define two mutually exclusive options simply defining a small function as explained in [real.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/program_options/example/real.cpp). For example, you can specify two conflicting (or depending) options defining a `conflicting_options()` function:

```
void conflicting_options(const boost::program_options::variables_map & vm,
                         const std::string & opt1, const std::string & opt2)
{
    if (vm.count(opt1) && !vm[opt1].defaulted() &&
        vm.count(opt2) && !vm[opt2].defaulted())
    {
        throw std::logic_error(std::string("Conflicting options '") +
                               opt1 + "' and '" + opt2 + "'.");
    }
}
```

and then calling

```
conflicting_options (vm, "quiet", "verbose");
```

right after `boost::program_options::store()`

I still don't understand if it's possible to define two mutually exclusive positional options, but that should be another question.

Comment: In my opinion it is so much boilerplate code! Why wouldn't boost support mutually exclusive groups like python's argparse does it?

Comment: Python is almost always more concise than C++, it's always been. C++11/14/17 are moving forward in this direction, but the pace is slow.